# django: by mistake deleted migration files from production server

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

By mistake I deleted all the migration files from all apps on production server.

Now running **`python manage.py makemigrations`** and then **`python manage.py migrate`** raises:

> "field already exists in the database"

error for each field, What should I do ?
django version: 1.7.7

Comment: If your migrations are all auto generated, then you don't need to run `migrate` anymore. Just run `makemigrations` and leave the migration file there. I think you might consider using version controls like `git` to track all files, so you don't lose anything.

Comment: Your code is all in version control, right? Just check out the latest version again and redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

If you already migrated and then deleted.Then `fake` will help you

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to fake the migration, the next command may help you:

```
python manage.py migrate 'name_app' 'name_migration' --fake
```

Example:

```
python manage.py migrate books 005_auto_20150505 --fake
```